# remove all the string except the pattern in regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am finding trouble with regex

I am having the below lines in  Notepad++

```
cyoe.LEVEL AS "level"
    ,cint.NAME AS "name"
    ,ji.dateAS "date"
```

i have written the `[a-zA-Z]+\"` to match all the `""` words

Now my task is i need to replace all the string except the one in the `""`

result should be something like below

```
"level"
"name"
"date"
```

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Using the search and replace function only?

Comment: @M'vy  Any thing is acceptable , But i am using windows

Comment: Try this one: ^([^\"]*)? Working for me in Sublime Text

Comment: @LeoPflug thanks yours looks fine and working

Answer (score 1):

I dont know where I am going wrong , but this should do it to an extent:

```
.(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

demo here :

http://regex101.com/r/jT5yA9

search and replace with blank

Answer (score 1):

Find `^[^"]*?(?=")` and replace with empty string. Use regular expression search mode.

- `^` Start of line.
- `[^"]` match anything but `"`.
- `*?` 0 or more times (lazy search)
- `(?=")` Make sure next character is `"` (lookahead, not included on match)

Comment: I am having something like this convert(NVARCHAR(10), cdl.LEVEL) AS degreelevel   from this i want to get degreelevel    so i need to find upto AS .